# Remove NaN values from pandas dataframes inside a list

Tags: pandas, nested-lists, nested-datalist

I have a number of dataframes inside a list. I am trying to remove NaN values. I tried to do it in a for loop:

```
for i in list_of_dataframes:
    i.dropna()
```

it didn't work but python didnt return an error neither. If I apply the code

```
list_of_dataframes[0] = list_of_dataframes[0].dropna()
```

to a each dataframe individually it works, but i have too many of them. There must be a way which I just can't figure out. What are the possible solutions?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't assign the new DataFrames with the dropped values to anything, so there was no effect.

Try this:

```py
for i in range(len(list_of_dataframes)):
    list_of_dataframes[i] = list_of_dataframes[i].dropna()
```

Or, more conveniently:

```py
for df in list_of_dataframes:
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Comment: The second one did it. Great job. Thank you!